# PHP - Traer peso de cada archivo/fichero en un ciclo

Tags: php

Buen día.
Necesito traer el peso de cada uno de los archivos (son todos imágenes) que hay dentro de un directorio.

```html
<?php
    $directorio = "vistas/img/productos";
    $scandir  = scandir($directorio, 1);
?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-12">
        <ul>
            <?php
                foreach($scandir as $key => $value){
                    echo '
                        <li>
                            '.$value.' - '.filesize($value).'
                        </li>'
                    ;
                }

                // anda bien si tomo un archivo o carpeta, pero no cuando hago el ciclo
                echo '<span>File Size: '.filesize($directorio).'</span>'
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Si quito el filesize me trae todos los archivos, es decir, una lista con el nombre de cada uno incluyendo su extensión. El problema es que al intentar aplicar filesize al value (a cada resultado que me trae el ciclo) entonces me sale junto a cada nombre de fichero:

Warning: filesize(): stat failed for (y acá el nombre de la imagen)

¿En qué estoy errando?

Comment: Debes pasarle la ruta completa a filesize, no sólo el nombre que es lo que retorna `scandir()` es decir algo como: `filesize('vistas/img/productos/' . $value)` además deberías de descartar las entradas `.` y `..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías concatenas $value con $directorio y con el '/'.

Te dejo el ciclo:

```
foreach($scandir as $key => $value)
{
    echo '<li>' . $value. ' - ' . filesize($directorio . '/' . $value) . '</li>';
}
```